# Why is Vim sometimes starting on random lines and other times only showing first lines of a file?

Tags: linux, vim

Vim sometimes only shows me some middle section of a file and other times only the beginning of the file (the first 30 or so lines). How do I change this to show all lines of the file? I read here to use a resize command but that didn't work.  I cannot scroll past this line number despite there being a lot more lines.   [image: I cannot scroll past this line in vim despite there being over 300 more lines]

Comment: Did you perhaps open that file previously and leave off in the middle of the file?

Comment: @JeffSchaller What do you mean? No it's a larger file and when I use :set number it shows that it's beginning on the 100th+ line.

Comment: I mean that vi (vim) can cache your position in a file, and I was wondering if you were seeing that behavior.

Comment: @JeffSchaller How do I check this? I wasn't aware of this. But I can't use the arrows to go up and down beyond the space available to me that it shows me.

Comment: Perhaps a picture or two would be helpful to point out the behavior you're seeing versus what you're expecting?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I updated the question with a picture. I cannot scroll past this line number despite there being a lot more lines.

Comment: Please test by opening a file in `vim`, then scrolling down to a line. Remember where you are. Exit and open the file again. Does `vim` return you to the same position as before?

Comment: @JeffSchaller It's starting from the 1st line and only showing up to 62. I then exited and did it again and it did the same thing (showed lines 1-62 but wouldn't let me scroll more).

Comment: Does your file contain extremely long lines?

Comment: @Kusalananda No. Around 140 characters max. Not long at all.